# Can I use credit cards without a chip and pin in Sweden?

Tags: payment-cards, sweden

I only have the magnetic credit cards not the chip/pin card. Can I still use my magnetic card in Sweden? What should I do if I cannot use my card?

Answer (score 6):

I was in Sweden in 2014 with an American credit card, and it was accepted literally every place I used it, both ATMs and shops. (Two different cards.) I don't recall trying an automated ticket dispenser (e.g., bus ticket) which I think would be the most likely to fail.

Comment: I was wondering if you had the chip or magnetic strip card that you used?

Comment: @Deee6 Magnetic stripe cards. Although I am changing banks accounts within the same bank to get a chip-and-pin card (only some types of accounts get them?!).

Answer (score 6):

Lacking a chip is not an issue. Almost all card readers are outfitted with both chip and magnetic strip readers. The only time I've seen a card reader without a magnetic stripe reader was in a food truck.

Not having a PIN is never an issue when there's a sales clerk around. You'll likely have to tell them that you don't have a PIN number (in Sweden, magnetic strip cards have PIN numbers too), but they should be able handle the transaction via a signed receipt instead.

Some vending machines do require PIN numbers (the vending machines used to top up the metro cards, most notably), but you can just visit a nearby Pressbyrån (a chain of convenience stores often located in the metro) or similar store to top those up instead.